# Report Service Manager Don't Display the classic interface

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportserver

i'm using SQL Server 2012 and i've created a report with The Data Tool.

Now i want to publish this report on the Server Report.I've changed the virtual folder in "ReportServer_MONITORING"

but when i write:

`http://<servername>/ReportServer_MONITORING`

I don't get the page of the manager but something like a simple exploration page:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to the Report Server Web Service web page; this is different from the Report Manager website.

You most likely need:

```
http://<servername>/Reports_MONITORING
```

You can confirm by looking in the Reporting Services Configuration manager and confirming the two URLs:

[image]